# What's the bad or ugly part of nodejs

Tags: node.js

I know the good part of nodejs, it uses event-driven, non-blocking I/O model and balabala. But as an experienced nodejs developer, what's the bad or ugly part of nodejs?

Any detailed situation or exemplified code will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily a bad thing but debugging nested callbacks is an issue. If you use something like express this is alleviated. If you are doing test driven development using Jasmine or something like that, debugging becomes a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

I don't consider it a *bad* thing, but `throw` doesn't work correctly in node.js. Hence, use of `throw` is discouraged.

Comment: `throw` works fine, just not as you might expect when you do it in a callback.